# Springboot Jpa using email as a foreignKey

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I had two tables. One of the ıs owner and other one is Bill. In the both table ı had email column. So ı want to use email as a ForeignKey. but owner ıd ıs became foreign key automaticly. how can ı do that?

This one is bill side

```
 @Id
private Long id;
private static final Integer LIMIT=200;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private Integer amount;
private String productName;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "email")
private PurchasingSpecialist owner;
```

And this one is owner side

```
@Id
private Long Id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;

@OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
)
@JoinColumn(name = "email",referencedColumnName = "email")
private List<Bill> bills;
```

but still owner_id column creating automaticly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You have to do is remove `Long id` attribute from PurchasingSpecialist Entity. And add `@Id` to email column. Then It will look like this. Then the JPA will create the email column as the primary key for the entity.

```
@Id
@Column(length = 200)
private String email;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;  
@OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
)
@JoinColumn(name = "email",referencedColumnName = "email")
private List<Bill> bills;
```

The next step is adding the `email` primary key to the Bill Entity.
When Using `@JoinColumn(name = "email",referencedColumnName = "email")` It will create a "email" column in Bill Entity. Therefore, `private String email;` in bill entity should be removed. Your Bill entity will look like this.

```
@Id
private Long id;
private static final Integer LIMIT=200;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Integer amount;
private String productName;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "email")
private PurchasingSpecialist owner;
```

The ER will look like this. I think this is the result you expected.

[image]